# MPJ Express -- runtime.MPJRuntimeException: Cannot connect to the daemon at machine <x> and port <10000>

Tags: mpj-express

i am facing problem while configuring MPJ Express in cluster mode.

i am following the guide given at
http://mpj-express.org/docs/guides/linuxguide.pdf

the environment variables are successfully Initialized as

1)
Set MPJ_HOME and PATH variables

**a.**  export MPJ_HOME=/path/to/mpj/

**b.**  export PATH=$PATH:$MPJ_HOME/bin

2)
the machines are also added successfully with a machines file as

**mpjboot  machines**

it shows message
starting mpjd...

3)
Next step is to test the HelloWolrd program by

**Compile: 
javac -cp .:$MPJ_HOME/lib/mpj.jar HelloWorld.java

10. Execute: mpjrun.sh -np 2 –dev niodev HelloWorld**

when i do that i get this error

**runtime.MPJRuntimeException: Cannot connect to the daemon at machine  and port <10000>**

The Platform i am using is

- Sun Ultra 25 workstations with Solaris 10 OS
- i have made a Fast Ethernet cluster of 2 machines
- ssh is enabled with root user on each machine
- network is established well

any help or solution is appreciated..

thank you

Comment: Any update about this?

Answer (score 1):

Examine the cluster nodes environment variables.

Try adding vars to `.bashrc` in each cluster node (ssh to it from main node):

```
echo 'export MPJ_HOME=/home/<user>/path/to/mpj' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$MPJ_HOME/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Alternately, turn on logging `/conf/wrapper.conf`, run and report your findings.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time i give an answer in stackOverflow.
I set up MPJExpress-v0_42 in my centos6.3 with jdk1.6.0_32, and finally everything seems OK.

### Question 1:   can not connect to daemon at machine and port

This may happens that the daemon is not running. You can give a try as follows:

1. you can use `sudo netstat -anp |grep port` to check whether the port is listening and also get the processId.
2. In my machine, after I started the daemon using `mpjdaemon -boot localhost`, I used the `sudo netstat -apn |grep 4000` command to check the port and got the followings.

   ```
   tcp        0      0 :::40000                    :::*                        LISTEN      8766/java           
   tcp        0      0 :::40001                    :::*                        LISTEN      8766/java
   ```

   the port is configured in `$MPJ_HOME/conf/wrap.conf` and my configuration is as follows:

   ```
   #port number for the daemon.
   wrapper.app.parameter.2=40001
   #Socket Server Port Number.
   wrapper.app.parameter.3=40000
   ```
3. I also use the `jps -m` command to get the java daemon process, the result is as follows:

   ```
   8766 MPJDaemon 40001
   30850 Jps -m
   ```

   Here `8766` is the processId as `netstat` shows, and `MPJDaemon` is the daemon process, `40001` is the listening port.

In your question, you cannot connect the daemon process. **Do the followings:**

1. you should check the port. If you cannot find the port using `netstat`, it generally means the `MPJDaemon is not running`.
2. To be sure, you can also using jps to check the process. Maybe process is running but the port is another one
3. Do not use the Cluster commands like `mpjboot machines` or `mpjrun.sh -np 2 -dev niodev HelloWorld`. You can use `mpjdaemon -boot localhost` to test current machine, if it is configured OK and you can set the machines file with one item of `localhost` and run Cluster commands.

**Other questions that I met.**

### Question 2: compile failed using ant

At first I use `MPJ-v0_44.zip` and `jdk1.6.0`, but it cannot compile and give an error that `ProcessBuilder has no method of "interNIO"(something like that)`. I analyse the source code and guess may be it is because JDK version is a litter lower. Given the fact that upgrading JDK is a litter complicated, I find another MPJ version of `mpj-v0_42.zip` and it compiled OK.

### Question 3: `mpjdaemon -boot localhost` with no error message, but MPJDeamon is not running.

After I configure the environment variables like `MPJ_HOME` from `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc`, the question is resolved. I don't know why.

### Question 4: command `jps -m` says "MPJDeamon is running" , but `mpjdaemon -status localhost` says "mpjdeamon is not running".

I use command (`ssh localhost nohup 'jps -m'`) and it says `jps` command not found, but i use jps the command works fine. I guess maybe it is the same question as above. The jps's path is not configured in path environment variable of `.bashrc`.  So after adding one line of `PATH=/jpspath:$PATH` in `.bashrc`, everything works fine.